# Codeigniter add validation for multiple element

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

My form has more than 50 different text inputs. I would like to use CodeIgniter's validations (like trim function) in the form validation library without creating a rule for each input. Is it to possible to combine them into one rule so I don't have to waste my time writing the same code over and over?

Comment: Make a function with validation credential, and pass your fields into that function.

Comment: text input with same name[]?

Comment: @kumar_v - no they have different name

Answer (score 0):

Change text field name as `group_name[your_txt_names]` in your view

```
<input name="group_name[your_txt_names]" value="" type="text" />
```

Then in controller, you can create a function.

```
$txt_bxes = $this->input->post("group_name");

$post_vals = array_map('trim', $txt_bxes);
```

Now you have trimmed values in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Kumar_v's idea was on the right track, if a bit silly in implementation

$this->input->post('var); merely reads the $_POST and runs some sanitation on it; the validation rules merely read the var from $_POST and apply your validation rule.

So if you only want to trim all $_POST vars, just trim your $_POST directly, then you can also run other validation afterwards.

Solution:

$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);

or

// take all posts and dump them into a variable at once

$input = $this->input->post(null, true);
$input = array_map('trim', $input);

Answer (score 0):

as the post data comes in array, I hope this will help you

```
$postData = $this->input->post();

array_walk($postData ,'myFunc');


function myFunc(&$value,$key){
  $value = trim($value);
}
```